# CSV to HTML DataTables filtering with buttons

Tags: datatables

I'm using CSV to HTML table: https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table, and I'd like to add button-based filtering (as seen here on the DataTables page: https://datatables.net/reference/option/)

I haven't manipulated the data much at this point, except to add scrollCollapse and pagingType, but I'm not entirely sure how to add the button instances for the CSV to HTML, as it seems to be done a little differently than the examples on DataTables.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function format_link(link){
    if (link)
      return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
    else
      return "";
  }

  CsvToHtmlTable.init({
    csv_path: 'data/foodsec_data.csv',
    element: 'table-container', 
    allow_download: true,
    csv_options: {separator: ',', delimiter: '"'},
    datatables_options: {"scrollCollapse": true,},
    datatables_options: {"pagingType": "simple_numbers",},
    custom_formatting: [[1, format_link]]
  });
```

Comment: I'd suggest rolling your own plugin and then you get full access to the DataTables instance. I guess the plugin above simply parses the CSV and generates the Table? This example (https://annoyingmouse.firebaseapp.com/mdb_table/) uses Papa Parse and works well.

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion!